Energy of the gravitational field within a sphere of radius $R$ in the Schwarzschild metric
The Landau-Lifshitz energy-momentum pseudotensor $t^{μν}$ is defined by
$$16πt^{μν} 
= -2G^{μν} - g^{-1} \left[ -g \left( g^{μν}g^{αβ} - g^{μα}g^{νβ} \right) \right]_{,αβ}$$
where $g=\text{det}[g^{μν}]$ and $G^{μν}=R^{μν}-\frac{1}{2}g^{μν}R$.
$\quad\quad$It is a standard result (Landay & Lifshitz, Vol. 2, Chap 96) that
$$\left[ (t^{μν} + T^{μν})√ \right]_{,ν}=0$$
using the short-hand notation $√ = \sqrt{-g}$.
$\quad\quad$Therefore, if $V$ is a sufficiently large spatial volume to include the entire system under consideration, the divergence theorem tells us that
$$\int_V (t^{μ0}+ T^{μ0})√ \, d^3 x$$
is constant as a function of time, and represents the total $μ$-momentum of the system. (This assumes (1) the integral converges, and (2) the integral of $(t^{μ0}+ T^{μ0})√$ vanishes on the boundary.)
$\quad\quad$If we compute $t^{00}$ explicitly for the Schwarzschild metric:
\begin{aligned}
g_{00} &= 1-2m/r\\
g_{11} &= -1(1-2m/r)^{-1}\\
g_{22} &= -r^2\\
g_{33} &= -r^2\sin^2{\theta}
\end{aligned}
then, also using $G^{μν}=0$ and $g=-r^4 \sin^2{\theta}$, we get
\begin{aligned}
t^{00} &= (-r^4 \sin^2{\theta})^{-1} \left[ (g^{00}g^{11})_{,11} + (g^{00}g^{22})_{,22} + (g^{00}g^{33})_{,33} \right]\\
&= (r^4 \sin^2{\theta})^{-1} \left[ (1-2m/r)r^2\sin^2{\theta} \right]_{,\theta\theta}\\
&= 2(1-2m/r)(r^2 \sin^2{\theta})^{-1} \left[ 1-2\sin^2{\theta} \right]\\
&= 2r^{-2}(1-2m/r) \left[ \csc^2{\theta}-2 \right]\\
\end{aligned}
$\quad\quad$If no other matter or energy fields are present, the total gravitational energy within a sphere of radius $R$ should be
\begin{aligned}
\int_{r<R}t^{00} \, d^3 x &= \int_{r<R} 2r^{-2}(1-2m/r)(\csc^2{\theta}-2) \, r\sin{\theta}\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi\\
&= 4\pi\int_0^R r^{-1}(1-2m/r)\,dr \int_0^\pi(\csc{\theta}-2\sin{\theta}) \,d\theta\\
\end{aligned}
Both these integrals diverge, even the angular one! (So the result would be divergent even for a spherical annulus $R_1 < r < R_2$.) What's going on?

What is wrong with explicitly "building a black hole" by integrating over the total energy, i.e. total mass energy minus gravitational energy released by lowering the mass towards the event horizon?

That's because the Landau Lifschitz pseudotensor only works in cartesian coordinates, while you used spherical ones, so no wonder you are getting the wrong results: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676035/24093
